# Building dataframes from one sheet in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a complex sheet in excel which I wish to read into multiple `pandas.DataFrames`.

[image]

Basically, there are 3 dataframes here. One for `DIRECTION_A`, `DIRECTION_B` and `TOTAL`.

How do I tell pandas to read each of these dataframes separately? I could use `iloc` to specify bounds but since I'm iterating over many different spreadsheets, there is a risk of different locations.

Presently, I'm reading all of these columns as one by skipping the top 7 rows:

```
tmp_df = pd.read_excel(file,sheetname=sheet_name,skiprows=7)
```

[(Sample data)](https://dropbox.com/s/30fypad6gwr5udl/sample.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you provide a (mock) xls file to test this?

Comment: Thanks :) . This - https://www.dropbox.com/s/30fypad6gwr5udl/sample.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can tell pandas to read the frames separately, but they can be easily separated after they are read in.

**Code:**

```
def get_multi_frame_excel(*args, **kwargs):
    # read in the frame, with a multi level column index
    multi_frame = pd.read_excel(*args, header=[0, 1], **kwargs)

    # group the data by the top level column index, and store in dict
    frames = {name: group for name, group in
              multi_frame.groupby(level=0, axis=1)}

    # remove the top level index from the frames
    for frame in frames.values():
        frame.columns = frame.columns.droplevel(level=0)

    # return a dict of frames
    return frames
```

**Test Code:**

```
frames = get_multi_frame_excel('SO_split_df.xlsx', skiprows=1)
for name, frame in frames.items():
    print('---')
    print(name)
    print(frame)
```

**Results:**

```
---
DIRECTION_A
Time      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
00:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
00:15:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
00:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
....
09:00:00  3  1  0  0  0  0  1  5
09:15:00  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  2
09:30:00  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  2
---
TOTAL
Time       A  B  C  D  E  F  G   H
00:00:00   1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
00:15:00   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
00:30:00   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
....
09:00:00   7  1  0  0  0  0  1   9
09:15:00   4  0  0  0  0  0  3   7
09:30:00   3  0  0  0  0  0  1   4
---
DIRECTION_B
Time       A  B  C  D  E  F  G   H
00:00:00   1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
00:15:00   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
00:30:00   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
....
09:00:00   4  0  0  0  0  0  0   4
09:15:00   3  0  0  0  0  0  2   5
09:30:00   2  0  0  0  0  0  0   2
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Using exactly the same input file, I am getting `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Passed header=[0,1] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns`

Comment: Stephen, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas `0.19.2`